# How to use EPPlus read an Excel 2010 file that has workbook protection?

Tags: c#, excel-2010, epplus

When I use the code below to read an Excel 2010 file that has password protection enabled for the workbook:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName,
       FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
     ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage();

     try
     {
         ep = new ExcelPackage(file);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         string strErr = ex.message;
     }
}
```

...I get an exception. Any example code to read a Excel 2010 file that has password protection, using EPPlus?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: When I put: 
ep = new ExcelPackage(file), I got exception: "Can not open the package. Package is an OLE compound document. If this is an encrypted package, please supply the password";

Comment: When I put: ep = new ExcelPackage(file, ""), I got exception: Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.

Comment: When I put: ep=new ExcelPackage(file, password), I got exception: it is invalid password. The password I put is a correct password

Answer (score 3):

Faced with the same problem. In Excel 2010 encryption algorythm is differs from 2007. Fortunately EPPlus 4.0 Beta 2 [was released](https://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/118053). Works fine with 2010+, but can not yet decrypt 2007 excel.

Comment: seems It doesn't support it so far