# Error reading xlsx (2007) file in EPPLUS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel-2007, epplus, epplus-4

I have an error while trying to read excel files (`xlsx`) which were saved in `Excel 2007` using `EPPlus` library.

Some workaround:

1. ASP.net mvc 5 app with EPPlus v. `4.0.4.0`
2. User can download template file from my site, then fill required data in it, and upload it back. File contains `4` worksheets, one of them is `hidden`. Workbook is password protected, worksheets are proteced too. All of them have different passwords. Template file (`xlsx`) produced in `Excel 2007 or 2010`.
3. When user posts file back I'm trying to open and read it using `EPPlus`
4. When I post file which was filled in Excel2010 everythins works fine. But when I post file from Excel 2007 a have an exception in `ExcelPackage` ctor.

Ok. Some code snippets now. There is my initial code of uploading and reading file using streams.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ActionName("ImportPublications")]
public async Task<JsonResult> AjaxImportPublications(int id, HttpPostedFileBase xlsImport) {
    AjaxExtResult result = new AjaxExtResult();

    if (xlsImport == null || xlsImport.ContentLength == 0) {
        result.Error = new[] { "Ошибка загрузки файла" };
        return Json(result);
    }

     try {
         using (var package = new ExcelPackage(xlsImport.InputStream)){ 
            // do something here
         }
         result.Success = true;
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
         result.Error = new[] { e.Message };
     }

     return Json(result);
}
```

The code above works with Excel 2010, but doesn't with 2007. **Exception is thrown then calling `ExcelPackage()` ctor.**

Debug data:

updloaded file `ContentType` is `"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"`

Exception details (disk write error):

```
Message:    "Ошибка на диске в процессе записи. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8003001D (STG_E_WRITEFAULT))"

StackTrace: 
at OfficeOpenXml.Utils.CompoundDocument.ILockBytes.WriteAt(Int64 ulOffset, IntPtr pv, Int32 cb, UIntPtr& pcbWritten)
at OfficeOpenXml.Utils.CompoundDocument.GetLockbyte(MemoryStream stream)
at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Load(Stream input, Stream output, String Password)
at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Load(Stream input)
at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage..ctor(Stream newStream)
at webDCReports.Controllers.MembersController.<AjaxImportPublications>d__56.MoveNext() ...
```

After that I tried to add workbook protection password to `ctor` paramters and changed code to

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(xlsImport.InputStream, "my_passwrod")) {
```

after that I've got new exception type: **"The stream must be read/write"**. It looks Ok as I do not save uploaded file, so I decided to save file and changed code to (without pwd):

```
var fi = new FileInfo(target);    
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fi)) {
```

and Exception details are:

```
Message: Can not open the package. Package is an OLE compound document. If this is an encrypted package, please supply the password.
Inner exception: "The file is not an valid Package file. If the file is encrypted, please supply the password in the constructor."
```

At this point, when I upload 2010-saved file - code works fine.
Adding workbook password to calling code gives me **Invalid password** Exception.

Actually it also looks Ok, as file itself is not password protected/encrypted.

**Does anyone know what is going on, how to fix this?**

*IMPORTANT UPDATE:*

I've removed `woorkbook` protection and file opens successfully.

Comment: found that Excel2007 & 2010 encryption algorythms differs. A year ago epplus 4 beta did not supprt 2007 encryption format. Looks like this is a reason why my code does not work in 2007 files.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671972/how-to-use-epplus-read-an-excel-2010-file-that-has-workbook-protection